# How to use the new angular material 2 menu bar

Tags: angular-material2

I am a little puzzled about the toolbar in [Angular Material 2](https://material.angular.io/components/component/toolbar).
How do I add toolbar items to it? should I put menu items in it?

I am trying to "move" a bootstrap navbar to Material.

I have read the documentation and who wants a menubar with 3 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: `</md-toolbar-row>`

E.g:

```
<md-toolbar color="accent">
  <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  <md-toolbar-row>
    <span>Second Line</span>
  </md-toolbar-row>
</md-toolbar>
```

You can see more: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/toolbar/toolbar-demo.html

Comment: Who wants a toolbar with 3 rows? I want something like this https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: What do you expect, someone doing everything for you? =)

What are you looking for is there, but you need to do something too ;)

Take a peek:
npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/menu